# XP SP3 Pro: Closing RDP session unlocks host computer screen

Tags: windows-xp, security, remote-desktop

When I close a RDP session from the client the host computer screen unlocks even though it was initially locked. How can this be fixed? This is a major security risk.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was in TeamViewer. After upgrading to version 5.1.10408 the problem disappeared.

I found this solution here: [link to answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-security/remote-desktop-leaves-console-session-unlocked/8018ab8b-013b-41b3-a830-3449f00d7783)